# SQL: How to delete rows from table based on a criteria

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

I have the following table:

```
tbl
source    type    date
---       ---     ---
google    A       2010-02-25
google    A       2013-04-11
facebook  C       2008-10-22
facebook  C       2007-01-28
```

I want to keep only a single entry of each source, and the criteria is select the source tuple with `min(date) group by source`. The table consists of millions of records, and I'm looking for an efficient way to delete redundant records.

Comment: Does this table have any unique identifier (i.e. primary key, id field etc.)?

Comment: @ChrisJ nah, it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In MySQL, you can do this using a `join`:

```
delete t
    from t join
         (select source, min(date) as mindate
          from t
          group by source
         ) tt
         on t.source = tt.source
    where t.date > tt.mindate;
```

The only way -- off-hand -- that I can think to make this more efficient is to store the aggregation result in a subquery and add an index to it.

I can also add that regardless of the computation for determining the rows to delete, deleting lots of rows in a table in inefficient.  Usually, I would recommend a three-step approach:

1. Write a query to generate the table you want and store the results in a temporary table.
2. Truncate the original table.
3. Re-insert the (much) smaller number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

In Microsoft SQL, you can try this.

```
;
WITH cte 
        AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY source, type
                                        ORDER BY createdate) RN
            FROM   tbsource)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE  RN > 1;
```

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I'm sorry. The question doesn't contain it is for MySQL.

Comment: There is a mysql tag, but probably should be in the title too if that's what it should be.

Comment: @mikato, Yeah correct! Even SQL tag is there which makes this question to see as a generic one.

Comment: And what is Microsoft SQL? Likely you meant Microsoft SQL Server or Microsoft TSQL. This is not splitting hairs since MS Access has a SQL dialect of its own distinct from MSSQL and both are MS products. And [Microsoft Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Use-Microsoft-Query-to-retrieve-external-data-42a2ea18-44d9-40b3-9c38-4c62f252da2e) spans several interfaces.

Comment: @Parfait, You're correct. I meant Microsoft SQL Server or Transact SQL here.

Comment: @Madhukar Thanks for your reply. I was looking for a MySQL query. Should have mentioned it in the title too. My mistake.

Comment: @SaadH, No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

```
delete from t where date not in (select al.d from (select min(date) as d  from t group by source )al);
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its long-term value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you've made.

Answer (score 0):

Add an identity column to the duplicate table as a serial number that acts as a row unique identifier(auto incremental ascending order):

```
 alter table tbl add sno int identity(1,1)
```

[image: table]

This query selects only non duplicated rows with min(date):

```
(select min(date),sno From tbl group by source)
```

So "sno" will be equals to "1" and "4".

Now join with this table, and delete the records of the join that are duplicated (t.sno is null)

```
delete E from tbl E
    left join
    (select min(date),sno From tbl group by source) T on E.sno=T.sno
where T.sno is null
```

[image: table3]

Solution adapted from method 3 of this link: [LINK](http://www.besttechtools.com/articles/article/sql-query-to-delete-duplicate-rows)